# How to get first element property value in Ajax response?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I'm returning a result from an Ajax call. The result looks like the following and I need to get only the count value ie, `32` of the first index in the returned response:

```
[{"Asset_Status":"active","Count":32},{"Asset_Status":"release","Count":7}]
```

What I did try is simply accessing the property value at index `[0]` but I get the error `property 0 is undefined`.

```
        function setAssetTileStatsOne(activeAssetCnt)
        {

            $("#activeAssetsLbl").text(activeAssetCnt.data[0].Count);

        }
```

**Question:**

How can you get the first element property value in Ajax response?

So the complete call from Ajax GET to the set method is as follows:

```
      $.ajax({
            url: asset_active_count_request_url,
            cache: false,
            success: function(activeAssetCnt){
                setAssetTileStatsOne(activeAssetCnt);
            }
        });



    function setAssetTileStatsOne(activeAssetCnt)
    {

        $("#activeAssetsLbl").text(activeAssetCnt.data[0].Count);

    }
```

Comment: what is activeAssetCnt and what is activeAssetCnt.data

Comment: have you tried `activeAssetCnt[0].Count`?

Comment: I've tried that too but the console tells me 'undefined' when logging the value. `console.log(activeAssetCnt[0].Count)
`  @vijayP

Comment: You're never parsing the JSON into an object. Either do `setAssetTileStatsOne( JSON.parse(activeAssetCnt) )` or change `$.ajax` into `$.getJSON`.

Comment: @Juhana that's the step I missed and fixed it. Didn't parse the JSON to an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

```
activeAssetCnt.data == [{"Asset_Status":"active","Count":32},{"Asset_Status":"release","Count":7}]
```

then `activeAssetCnt.data[0].Count` will be resolved to `32`.

Maybe you want just `activeAssetCnt[0]`?

**EDIT:**

Ok, according to your comment the following is true:

```
activeAssetCnt == [{"Asset_Status":"active","Count":32},{"Asset_Status":"release","Count":7}]
```

That means `activeAssetCnt[0]` will give you `{"Asset_Status":"active","Count":32}`. `activeAssetCnt[0].Count` should therefore resolve to `32`.

Comment: That was a mistake the array returned is just `activeAssetCnt`. I did try `                console.log(activeAssetCnt[0].Count)
` but I get an error in console telling me undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: Do `console.log(activeAssetCnt)`, please, and post the output.

Comment: The result of console.log(activeAssetCnt) is `[{"Asset_Status":"active","Count":32},{"Asset_Status":"release","Count":7}]` Trying `var count = response[0].count;` gives an undefined error in the console as suggested above.

Comment: I updated the answer, please have a look. I am assuming that the `&quot;` in your previous post is actually a `"` character and that `activeAssetCnt` is an actual object, not a JSON string.

Comment: Calling `JSON.parse(activeAssetCnt) )` is what fixed the issue, I can access the property value now. I hadn't parsed the returned Ajax result into an object.As @Juhana suggested.

Answer (score 2):

So let's say the actual response from the server is your first code above; I'm going to set it to a variable called `response`.

```
var response = [{"Asset_Status":"active","Count":32},{"Asset_Status":"release","Count":7}];
```

To access the first count, you'd do this.

```
var count = response[0].count;
```

We've set the response variable as the given array and can access the array elements using the 0 index. From there, we access the object properties using dot notation. We could also access the first count like this:

```
var count = response[0]['count'];
```

To access the second count, you'd do this:

```
var second = response[1].count;
```